# pip install does not install local module/package from setup.cfg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, pipenv

I have the following Pipfile and setup.cfg, and when I perform `pip install -e .` it installs the packages under `install_requires` but not the local package.

Pipfile --

```py
[[source]]
url = "https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@${HOST}"
verify_ssl = true
name = "python"

[packages]
    my-cli = {editable = true, path = "."}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

setup.cfg --

```py
[metadata]
name = my-cli
version = 0.1.0
[options]
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
   click
   PyYaml
   jsonschema

[options.package_data]
mymodule.resources = *.*
```

When I run `pip list` I can only see the following:

```
Package      Version   Location
------------ --------- -------------------------
click        8.0.3
PyYaml       3.13
jsonschema   4.1.2
```

But I cannot see my-cli package.

Comment: I'm confused why you have the Pipfile in the first place. The Pipfile is only used by pipenv, **not by plain pip install**. What happens when you instead `pipenv install`?

Comment: The issue is resolved now, basically the pip install was happening within a ubuntu image and just ended up enabling venv, "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.9-venv" "RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv"

Comment: Ohh cool. I don't have time to post a full answer now, but since you have a Pipfile, you can also install `pipenv` (which also creates a venv) and do `pipenv install`.

Answer (score 0):

A **Pipfile** is used by [**pipenv**](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), not by regular/plain pip.

See https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#example-pipfile-pipfile-lock:

> #### Example Pipfile & Pipfile.lock
>
> Pipfiles contain information for the dependencies of the project, and
> supersedes the requirements.txt file used in most Python projects. You
> should add a Pipfile in the Git repository letting users who clone the
> repository know the only thing required would be installing Pipenv in
> the machine and typing `pipenv install`. Pipenv is a reference
> implementation for using Pipfile.

Doing

```
pip install -e .
```

will not read your Pipfile.

You need to instead use either

```
pipenv install -e .
```

to install your editable dependency *and* to add it to the **Pipfile**

OR

```
pipenv install
```

if the editable dependency is already in the Pipfile and you just want `pipenv` to do the install operation.

Either way, `pipenv` will install both your editable dependency (`my-cli`) and all its required dependencies defined in **setup.cfg**, **setup.py**, and **pyproject.toml** (following the rules in the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) docs).

You can do `pipenv graph` to see the installed packages

```
sample-module$ pipenv graph
my-cli==0.1.0
  - click [required: Any, installed: 8.0.3]
  - jsonschema [required: Any, installed: 4.3.3]
    - attrs [required: >=17.4.0, installed: 21.4.0]
    - pyrsistent [required: >=0.14.0,!=0.17.2,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.0, installed: 0.18.0]
  - PyYaml [required: Any, installed: 6.0]
```

which shows the packages listed in `package_requires` to be sub-dependencies of `my-cli`.

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428338/pip-install-does-not-install-local-module-package-from-setup-cfg#comment124539250_70428338):

> The issue is resolved now, basically the pip install was happening within a ubuntu image and just ended up enabling venv, "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.9-venv" "RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv"

Great. Both Python's built-in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) provide a way of creating and maintaining virtual environments. You can learn about `pipenv` from its [Basic Usage](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#basic-usage-of-pipenv) tutorial. The main difference, I would say, is that pipenv maintains a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock to track the virtual env's packages.

Use whichever is more convenient.